# Typo3: wrap image with sys_category

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I'd like to wrap the standard typo3 image with a css, containing the sys_category.

Like

```
<div class="**TYPO3 CATEGORIES**"><img .... ></div>
```

Trying now for several days without success :-(

Answer (score 1):

Your questions is really not clear, but if you wanted every image (e.g. in a "Text and Pictures" content element) to be wrapped with a div containing the categories of the page in the class attribute, you can use the following code. Make sure you change the value of "pidInList"!

```
tt_content.image.20.1.stdWrap.prepend = COA
tt_content.image.20.1.stdWrap.prepend {
  10 = TEXT
  10.value = <div class="
  20 = CONTENT
  20 {
    table = sys_category
    select {
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# --- enter the uid of the page containing your categories here
      pidInList = 123
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
      selectFields = sys_category.title AS cattitle
      join = sys_category_record_mm ON sys_category_record_mm.uid_local = sys_category.uid
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# --- use pid here if you want the categories of the page
# --- use uid here if you want the categories of the content element
      where.field = pid
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
      where.intval = 1
      where.wrap = sys_category_record_mm.uid_foreign=|
      orderBy = sys_category_record_mm.sorting_foreign
      languageField = sys_category.sys_language_uid
    }
    renderObj = TEXT
    renderObj {
      field = cattitle
      noTrimWrap = || |
    }
    stdWrap.ifEmpty.cObject = TEXT
    stdWrap.ifEmpty.cObject.value = no-categories
  }
  40 = TEXT
  40.value = ">
}
tt_content.image.20.1.stdWrap.append = TEXT
tt_content.image.20.1.stdWrap.append.value = </div>
```

If the page has categories cat1 and cat2 checked and the categories are stored in a page with uid 123, this code should result in `<div class="cat1 cat2 "><img ...></div>` for every image in a "Text and Pictures" or "Pictures" content element.